# Calculate the norm of the operator $\phi_r(f)=\displaystyle{\int_{0}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^r}\, dt}$, where $0<r<1$ and $f\in C[0,1]$, $f(0)=0$.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

By the property of the integral,
$|\phi_r(f)|=\left|\displaystyle{\int_{0}^1\frac{f(t)}{t^r}\,dt}\right|\leq\displaystyle{\int_{0}^1\left|f(t)\right|\frac{1}{|t^r|}\,dt}\leq \left(\displaystyle{\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{|t^r|}\,dt}\right)\|f\|.$
Therefore $\phi_r$ is bounded and therefore continuous, and also $\|\phi_r\|\leq \displaystyle{\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{|t^r|}\,dt}=\displaystyle{\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{t^r}\,dt}=\left[\frac{t^{-r+1}}{-r+1}\right]_{0}^1=\frac{1}{-r+1}.$

It remains to prove the opposite inequality to show that the norm of the operator in question is $\frac{1}{-r+1}$, this is where I need a suggestion as I have not been able to achieve it.

Comment: The norm is $a/(1-r)$ to get a sequence of functions that  approximately attain the bound, I,e, $\phi_r(f_n)\approx 1/(1-r)$ consider piecewise linear functions that quest $0$ at $0$ and $1$ over the interval $[1/n,1]$.

Comment: Let $f_n(t) = \min(nt,1)$. Note that $\|f_n\|=1$. Compute $\lim_n\phi_r(f_n)$.

Comment: Apparently the function $f_n(t)=\displaystyle{\min_{t\in[0,1]}\{nt,1\}}$ is not continuous . I think this observation is pertinent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq C([0, 1])$ that is given by
$$
f_n(t) :=
\begin{cases}
nt & ,~ 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n} \\
1 & ,~\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $\lVert f_n \rVert = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$
\lVert \phi_r \rVert\geq \left \lvert \phi_r(f_n) \right \rvert = \left \lvert \int^\frac{1}{n}_0 \frac{n}{t^{r-1}}~\mathrm{d}t + \int_\frac{1}{n}^1 \frac{1}{t^r}~\mathrm{d}t \right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac{1}{n^{2-r}(2-r)} + \frac{1}{1-r}- \frac{1}{n^{1-r}(r-1)}\right \rvert 
$$
Now $\lVert \phi_r \rVert \geq \frac{1}{1-r}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.